# Referencing variables in a shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

In a shell script, if I define a variable such as `FOO=25`, is there a difference between referencing it as `$FOO$` and `${FOO}$`?

Comment: You must not use the `$` in the end! It will be treated as normal character and not as part of the variable name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In most situations both `$var` and `${var}` are the same. (Note that you must not use a `$` at the end!)

One example where you need curly braces are when you need to put a variable in a continuous string.

Example:

```
var=hel
echo ${var}lo
```

will output `hello`.

Answer (score 13):

To answer your main question, `${foo}` is called ["parameter expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). To be precise, the `$` itself starts parameter expansion, the `{ }` are actually optional according to [the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), but can be useful to indicate the end of the variable's name:

```
$ foo="bar"
$ echo $fooBaz   ## fails, no variable named $fooBaz exists

$ echo ${foo}Baz ## works, $foo is expanded and the string Baz is appended
barBaz
```

Basically, `$foo` and `${foo}` are identical. Apart from cases like the above or when you are doing [string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), they are completely  equivalent.

However, you shouldn't really use either of them. The rule of thumb is that, with very few exceptions, you should *always* use `"$foo"` or `"${foo}"` and never `$foo` or `${foo}`. You should always quote your variables to avoid invoking the split+glob operator (more on that later).  You certainly don't want `$foo$`. The final `$` is irrelevant:

```
$ foo="bar"
$ echo "$foo$"
bar$
```

So, while unquoted variables are sometimes OK:

```
$ echo $foo
bar
```

They are usually not and should really be avoided:

```
$ if [ -n $foo ]; then echo empty; else echo "not empty"; fi ## fails
empty

$ if [ -n "$foo" ]; then echo empty; else echo "not empty"; fi ## works
not empty
```

Note that the brackets do not help here either:

```
$ if [ -n ${foo} ]; then echo empty; else echo "not empty"; fi  ## fails
empty

$ if [ -n "${foo}" ]; then echo empty; else echo "not empty"; fi ## works
not empty
```

When you use `$foo` or `${foo}`, the shell will **split** the value saved in the variable on whitespace (this can be changed by setting the `IFS` variable to something else) into a list and then,  each element of the list is treated as a **glob** pattern and expanded into any matching files or directories. This is known as the *split+glob* operator. To illustrate, consider a directory with two files:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct  9 18:16 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct  9 18:16 file2
```

Now, let's set a variable to `foo *`:

```
$ foo="foo *"
```

What happens if we try to check if a file with that name exists?

```
$ if [ -e $foo ]; then echo "file exists"; else echo "no such file"; fi
file exists
```

The variable was split into `foo` and `*` and, since `*` is a wildcard that matches any string, the shell tells you that a file called `foo *` exxists. However, if we quote it correctly, this doesn't happen:

```
$ if [ -e "$foo" ]; then echo "file exists"; else echo "no such file"; fi
no such file
```

That was a trivial example to illustrate the point. Imagine if I had used `rm` instead of `echo` though.

So, first rule: **always quote your variables.** You can use either `"$foo"` or `"${foo}"` but quote it either way. For more detail on using variables safely, have a look at these posts:

- [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899/22222)
- [Expansion of a shell variable and effect of glob and split on it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108963/22222)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222)
- [Why do I need to quote variable for if, but not for echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65624/22222)

Comment: I didn't want to edit your otherwise excellent answer, but shouldn't `$ var="foo *"` be `$ foo="foo *"`? You don't use `var` anywhere.

Comment: @Joe oh, good grief! Yes, of course it should, thanks for pointing it out. Feel free to fix such mistakes by suggesting an edit, by the way. That sort of thing is very much encouraged, precisely to avoid silly errors like this one.